# Check for null of empty variable not working as it should

Tags: php, null

Its a minor thing but i am stucked in it don't know why php treats it like this. please tell me the reason for this.

```
$variable = null;
if( $variable !== NULL || $variable != ' '){
    echo "its not null or empty";
    }else{
    echo "Its null or empty";
}
```

The Output is `"its not null or empty"`. Please tell me the reason and solution for this.

Comment: The `||` operator. Either use `&&` or check for equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an or-condition. For each case you're testing if it is not equal.

Consider this case. Given that `a` is not equal to `b`, then the condition `x != a || x != b` will ALWAYS be true.

What you want to use is the and-operator:

```
if( $variable !== NULL && $variable != ' ')
```